# 'Datetime2 to a Datetime resulted in out-of-range value' when using TimeSpan with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, timespan

I have a table with several `time(7)` (allowing NULLS) columns in my SQL Server database. My application uses Entity Framework to store entities in the database.

I use `Nullable<TimeSpan>` as data type corresponding to the 'allowing NULLS time(7)' in my SQL Server database. When I execute `SaveChanges()` after adding an entity with the `TimeSpan?` column, it throws an ListInternalException saying the well known

> 'The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

I have already met this exception before and know that it is because the .Net datetime mi value is lower than `SqlDateTime.MinValue`. But here we don't have date to count from. Moreover my property and column types are Nullable and the exception persists when I set the properties to be Null.

Any suggestions how to deal with that problem?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyEntity]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AssociationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IsMondayDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsTuesdayDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsWednessdayDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsThursdayDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsFridayDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSaturdayDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSundayDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MondayFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [TuesdayFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [WednesdayFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [ThursdayFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [FridayFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [SaturdayFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [SundayFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [MondayTo] [time](7) NULL,
    [TuesdayTo] [time](7) NULL,
    [WednessdayTo] [time](7) NULL,
    [ThursdayTo] [time](7) NULL,
    [FridayTo] [time](7) NULL,
    [SaturdayTo] [time](7) NULL,
    [SundayTo] [time](7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyEntity] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PK_MyEntity] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PK_MyEntity_PK_MyAssociation] 
    FOREIGN KEY([FBOId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MyAssociation] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyEntity] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyEntity_MyAssociation]
GO
```

My entity:

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid OtherTableId { get; set; }

    public bool IsMondayDayOff { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? MondayFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? MondayTo { get; set; }

    public bool IsTuesdayDayOff { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TuesdayFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? TuesdayTo { get; set; }

    public bool WednesdayOff { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? WednesdayFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? WednesdayTo { get; set; }

    public bool ThursdayOff { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? ThursdayFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? ThursdayTo { get; set; }

    public bool FridayOff { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? FridayFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? FridayTo { get; set; }

    public bool SaturdayOff { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? SaturdayFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? SaturdayTo { get; set; }

    public bool SundayOff { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? SundayFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? SundayTo { get; set; }

    public virtual AnotherEntity Association  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `time` type represents the time of day, not a duration. You can't store anything longer than 24 hours. What are you trying to save in there?

Comment: I am testing with DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay. Also I am testing it with Null values as well, since the columns in the DB are 'allow null. The result is the same.

Comment: The error messages says otherwise. It says you tried to save a `datetime2` type into a `datetime` column, or vice versa. Either you are using the wrong types, or the error is about a *different* column. Post your table schema and class.

Comment: They are no datetime2 columns/properties neither in my class nor in the database schema. Will post it, right now.

Comment: If you were to remove the timeSpan column, is it saving correctly? Are you using an int for your timeSpan or a Datetime?

Comment: Thousands of developers use  Entity Framework, TimeSpan and `time` without issues. It's not broken. You have to post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: BTW .NET never converts `TimeSpan` to `DateTime`. EF will try to do this only if you actually force it, by mixing up the types. The very fact that you tried to use `SqlDateTime.MinValue` means that you *have* mixed up the typs at least once

Comment: Post a *minimal example* that *does reproduce* the error. What you posted is just a class. This doesn't prove anything. Where is the table schema? Where is the code you used to save the entity? What is the *full* exception string, including the call stack?

Comment: I have never tried to use SQLDAteTime.Min value. I just mentioned that 'datetime2 to datetime' issue is provided by the difference between SQL and .net datetime types min values. I do nowhere mix DateTime and TimePsan in my code. I use only time(7) and TimeSpan as I've mentioned above.

Comment: And yet, the error says that you do. Post a reproducible example. You can't be the *first* developer that tried to store `TimeSpan?` into a nullable `time` column

Comment: Launch SQL Server Profiler. Exec your SaveChanges() and you'll catch the code passed to server that causes the error. In that code search for datetime2/datetime columns

Comment: +1 on what sepupic said. The error may be raised by a *related* entity, not `FBOBusinessHour`. Or you may be targeting the wrong database. That's a very common mistake with user instance connection strings. You didn't post the full error, so it's impossible to say what raised this error.

Comment: The Related entity neither has any column/property of any datetime related type. @sepupic the SqlProfiler was a good suggestion. I will try it right now

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos you were right. The problem was caused by a second level association (an association of the association which had datetime2 column). I caught it using the profiler as you and sepupic suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was not how EF handles time(7) and TimeSpan data types but MyEntity's second level association (association of an association) that had datetime2 column which was not provided when adding the entity to the database. Fond it using the SQL Server Profiler as suggested by @sepupic in the comments. Thanks.